# Throwing exception when the same key inserted into std::map

Tags: c++, stl

I use VS2010 and I noticed when I add a key:value pair into std::map,if the similar key is already in the map, then the insertion is ignored.So for example:

```
     std::string pipeName = "pipe1";
_pipes.insert(std::make_pair(pipeName,ppl));
    _pipes.insert(std::make_pair(pipeName,ppl));
```

This operation results in only one pair stored in the map.I would like to throw an exception in such a case.So yes,I can just compare before the insertion if the key already exists, but can std::map be forced to throw it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the return value and throw the exception yourself:

```
auto p = _pipes.insert(std::make_pair(pipeName,ppl));
if (!p.second)
{
  // insert failed, throw something
}
```

Obviously this could be wrapped in a helper function or class.

Comment: Yes I see now,probably will use something like this.

Answer (score 4):

> can std::map be forced to throw it?

No.  The behaviour of `std::map` is well-defined, and doesn't include throwing exceptions on duplicate insertions.  If you want this behaviour, you should write a wrapper class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.But since @juanchopanza has less points than you I will give it to him ;)